# how to scroll to bottom of scrollview in React native 0.63?

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-ios

How to scroll to the bottom of any list using hooks in React Native 0.63?
When I do

```
const scrollviewref = useRef(ScrollView);

<ScrollView
        ref={scrollviewref}
        onContentSizeChange={scrollviewref
          .getNode()
          .scrollTo({ animated: true }, 0)}
      >
```

it says scrollviewref.getNode is not a function
or

```
<ScrollView
        ref={scrollviewref}
        onContentSizeChange={scrollviewref
          .scrollTo({ animated: true }, 0)}
      >
```

it says scrollviewref.scrollTo is not a function

I have added

```
scrollviewref.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true });
```

inside useEffect but the scrollis not happening immediately, any suggestions why?

Could anyone please help me out here?
Any leads would be great.

Comment: There's a method **scrollToEnd** for this. Look at [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/scrollview#scrolltoend) official documentation for reference for available props and methods.

Comment: have added scrollToEnd function and edited the question, now the scroll is not happening immediately, any suggestion?

Comment: Probably because `{ animation: true }`. Try `scrollToEnd({ animated: false })`.